# Area calc gives odd answers

Tags: qgis, vector, area

I made a shapefile from a DEM raster of Ethiopia, and I want to find the total area of the shapefile. I have changed the CRS of all files to Africa_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic (ESPG: 102022), and the units are meters. I have tried using the field calculator, but the answers are very small. I have also used the identify features tool, and the answers are the same as the field calculator's.

I also used "count" in the field calculator to get the number of pixels, but these sometimes seem very small too. The pixel size is 0.000277778,-0.000277778, but I don't know what the units are, so I am not sure how to use that to find the area.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image: CRS]
[image: Units]

I tried using the measure area tool where you draw a polygon, but this gave a very small answer too.
[image]

I read there might be a way to do it with GRASS, but I have a problem with my GRASS plugin which I don't understand.
[image]
[image]

Comment: I think something's gone wrong in your reprojection to Albers. Take a look at the scale at the bottom. 1:62 - are the distances on the screen really only 62x larger in real life?

Comment: It looks like you used the wrong method for changing the projection. Check out the answer to this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/280489/new-geocoded-points-layer-misaligned-with-polygon-layer/280537#280537

Comment: Your pixel sizes will not be so small once you correctly project into an SI-based projection (i.e. meters). They are currently in degrees (e.g. epsg:4326)